# how to get how many Friday available in each month using each month of LocalDate in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I want count of total Friday available in each month. How to get that?

1.code

```
private static int getFridayCount(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, LocalDate startDate) {
    return // 
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `dayOfWeek` and `startDate` parameters? Shouldn't the method have a `YearMonth` parameter instead?

Comment: If you are interested in Fridays only, why does the method have a `DayOfWeek` as parameter?

Comment: Because of DayOfWeek we can pass any day like Monday Or Wednesdays etc startDate means each month of any date i have to pass

Comment: See [Count days between two dates with Java 8 while ignoring certain days of week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25798876/2711488)…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the fastest, but I find this really simple to understand:

```
public static int numberOfDaysOfWeekInMonth(DayOfWeek dow, YearMonth yearMonth) {
    LocalDate startOfMonth = yearMonth.atDay(1);
    LocalDate first = startOfMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(dow));
    LocalDate last = startOfMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(dow));
    return (last.getDayOfMonth() - first.getDayOfMonth()) / 7 + 1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
System.out.println(
    numberOfDaysOfWeekInMonth(
        DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, YearMonth.of(2020, 9)
    )
); // outputs 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You may count every `dayOfWeek` from `startDate` to end of month like

```java
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 9 ,25);
        System.out.println("Amount: " + getCountOfDayInMonth(dow, startDate));
    }

    private static int getCountOfDayInMonth(DayOfWeek dow, LocalDate startDate) {
        LocalDate date = startDate;
        int count = 0;
        while (date.getMonth() == startDate.getMonth()) {
            if (date.getDayOfWeek() == dow) {
                count++;
            }
            date = date.plusDays(1);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Where `date` is a `LocalDate` beginning at `startDate` and going through the current `Month`.

Comment: i can pass startDate means their is not startDate of any month its just date of each month which are any date

Comment: Then why don't you directly pass a `Month` object ? If you want an answer for the whole month not regarding the startDate you pass, I suggest you to look at @Sweeper answer