# Determine number of business days between two dates

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I know that there are a lot of similar questions asked before, but i need extensible way to determine number of business days in the specified period.

For the beginning it would be enough to determine business day by day of the week
but there also should be some easy way to set custom *HolidayHandler* where we can specify holidays which won't be taken into account in the calculation of business days.

Does someone have any examples how to achieve this? Using Joda Time or stuff like that(without reinventing the wheel).

Also it would be a good addition if there is a way to calculate not only the days but also hours and minutes(2d 12h 56m for example)

Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143194/difference-between-two-dates-including-only-business-days-i-e-excluding-weeke

Comment: this would help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798876/count-days-between-two-dates-with-java-8-while-ignoring-certain-days-of-week